# Javascript time vs PHP time , not the same

Tags: javascript, php, time

i'm having a (older) mobile webpage that shows the current time in the footer of that page. Now i've added some PHP code to it, to have the user select a starting time of a working timer.

I noticed that the Javascript time is 2 minutes ahead of the PHP time.

JS :

```
var currentTime = new Date()
var hours = currentTime.getHours()
var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes()
document.write(hours + ":" + minutes)
```

PHP :

```
echo date('H:i');
```

as i said, the difference is about 2 minutes, how is that even possible? both should be server time ??

Comment: JavaScript will be the time on the Client, PHP will be the time on the server.

Comment: JS is local PC time, PHP is server time.

Comment: How could a javascript date object, which is constructed on the client's machine, have the server's time?

Answer (score 4):

**JS** shows client side time. **PHP** shows time which is on server.

Answer (score 1):

Javacript is the time of the user...eg it may be 2 minutes if my pc time is 2 minutes ahead, or it might be difference in hours if different timezone from server!!

Php will always show server's time.